# Задачка по программированию

Tags: c++, c, borland-c++

> По древней легенде мудрец, который изобрел шахматы, потребовал от персидского шаха такое количество пшеницы, чтобы им можно было покрыть шахматную доску, положив на первую клетку 1 зерно, на вторую - 2, на третью - 4 и т.д., т.е. на каждую следующую в двое больше предыдущей. Каким количеством зерна можно покрыть шахматную доску?

Вот код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>
void main()
{long int s, k, i;
clrscr;
s=1;
for(i=1;i<=64;i++)
{k=exp(i*log(2));
 s+=k
}
printf("Kol-vo zeren=%50d\n",s);
getch();
}
```

Проблема в том, что код выдаёт неправильный ответ, да еще и с минусом. Не понимаю почему, да и судя по пособиям - цикл задан правильно

Comment: У вас переполнение переменной `k`. При достижении чересчур больших значений целые переменные уходят в минус. Почитайте, например, [это обсуждение](/research/212424/). (Там про Java, но с C++ та же история.)

Comment: Эмм, и как это исправлять? Ни разу не сталкивался с переполнением)

Comment: @Treaq:

1. Попробуйте увеличить разрядность вашей переменной. Например, вместо `long` возьмите `long long`. Это поможет на некоторое время.
2. Используйте вместо целого типа тип с плавающей запятой. Там пределы ещё больше. НО всё-таки рано или поздно вы упрётесь в предел.
3. Используйте специальные арифметические типы произвольной точности. (например, [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) или [boost::multiprecision](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/intro.html)). Встроенных в язык таких типов нет.

Comment: @Treaq: Кстати, вы можете в точности оценить, сколько вам понадобится. Максимальное слагаемое — `2^64`, поэтому вам нужно по крайней мере 128-битный целый тип.

(На самом деле, легко самому подсчитать, что ответ будет `2^65 - 1`.)

Comment: @VladD, достаточно беззнакового 64-битного типа.

Comment: @VladD, первое слагаемое — 2^0, второе — 2^1, последнее — 2^63. Сумма их всех — (2^64 - 1).

Comment: Из /usr/include/limits.h

    #   define ULLONG_MAX 18446744073709551615ULL

или по простому -- все биты 1 в 64-bit целом.

Comment: @falstaf: Мне казалось, последнее слагаемое `2^64`, а 64-битный беззнаковый тип от 0 до `2^64 - 1`. То есть, хватить не должно.

---
У TC в коде сумма от `2^1`, `i` от 1 до 64, а не от 0 до 63.

Comment: @VladD, согласен, у ТС неверный цикл. По условию задачи на первой клетке должно лежать одно зерно, а не два.

Comment: опять эти циклы для прогрессий... школу отменили чтоль?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тип `long` включает в себя диапазон значений `[–2147483,648; 2147483647]` (или же `[0; 4294967295]`, в случае `unsigned long`). Очевидно, что значение

```
18 446 744 073 709 551 615
```

являющееся ответом к этой задаче, в указанные диапазоны не попадает. Как следствие — у вас происходит переполнение. Почитайте, например, [тут](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/DE18T05o/).

Решение: использовать `unsigned long long`.

Comment: Ну, это смотря какая разрядность системы. 32-битный `long` на сегодня довольно редкая штука.

---
Хм, беру свои слова назад. У MSVC 2013 `long` [32-битный](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx).

Comment: Всё равно не помогает. Отказывается выдавать правильный ответ

Comment: @Treaq, Вы хотите, чтобы Ваша программа с `exp()` и `log()` заработала?

Не заработает. [Размер мантиссы](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) в `double` (результат этих функций) всего 52 бита.

Comment: @avp: Точно. Из-за ошибок округления результат будет отличаться.

Answer (score 0):

Так как количество зёрен с каждой клеткой удваивается, можно представить результат в виде двоичного числа:

```
1*2^0 + 1*2^1 + ... + 1*2^63
```

Есть ничто иное, как полностью забитое единицами 64битное целое.
Известно, что такое число(все биты включены) представляет также `-1` в знаковом представлении.

Поэтому решением задачи может быть просто каст:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  std::cout << (uint64_t) -1 << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Вы конечно молодец, что переписали комментарии трехлетней давности от VladD и falstaf в виде бесполезного ответа, но я бы Вас за это точно не похвалил.

Comment: @AlexKrass, обвинили меня неизвестно в чём. Ссылку хоть дайте

Comment: Упс, на даты-то я и не посмотрел, извините. Это @Kromster виноват

Comment: Но мне не понадобился 128битный тип, не так ли? И про каст из -1 там ни слова

Comment: Как хотите, но по мне следствие очевидно. В общем-то дело Ваше, я свое мнение высказал. По крайней мере вопрос подразумевает не нахождение правильного ответа, а выяснение причины его неправильности в коде ТС.